# Python 3.9 sockets issue sending data to client sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I have been creating a chatroom application in python using socket and tkinter. Whenever I try to send a message to the server I get the following error:

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

Code:

```
print("Sending message from server")

for clientKey in data.sockets.keys():
    data.sockets[clientKey]["socket"].send(bytes(f"{data.sockets['server']['username']}: {message}", "utf-8"))

log(f"{data.sockets['server']['username']}: {message}")
print("Sent message from server")
```

The program gets as far as the first print statement.

For context, I have a tkinter text widget and the function `log(text)` just inserts the text into the widget. It has nothing to do with the socket module. For even more context, this is what a client's information looks like in the `data` class:

```
data.sockets["server"] = {"socket": sock,
    "username": "Host",
    "thread": threading.Thread(target = receiveMessages, daemon = True)}
data.sockets["server"]["thread"].start()
```

This is the server's information, but it is the same layout for the clients.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I never created the `if clientKey != "server"`, meaning every time I tried to send a message from the server, it would attempt to send a message to the server, which obviously isn't possible.